# Why does the error ORA-00907 Missing right parenthesis occur on my table?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have three tables: Holiday, school, pay. The school table's primary key is made up of the holiday and pay's primary key as it is a link table. Why does the error occur on my table?

Answer (score 1):

The data type for dates is date, not date().  Delete the () - you have that in two places. This will clear your first error.

You (will) *may* get further error messages - write back if you need more help.

(EDITED: I realized the next error on my system was about inexistent tables - obviously since I don't have the OP's referenced tables)

Comment: thank you, what further error messages will I get and why?

Comment: Actually, perhaps there will be no further errors; on my machine the statements complains about inexistent tables (obviously, since I don't have your parent tables). Give it a try and see.

Answer (score 0):

The `date` type doesn't take any arguments. You should remove the empty parenthesis you have after it:

```
CREATE TABLE Subscription
( 
    Club_ID varchar(10), 
    Member_ID varchar(10),
    Current_or_Old_Subscription varchar(50) CONSTRAIN Current_or_Old_Subscription_nn NOT NULL,
    Subscription_StartDate date, -- here!
    Subscription_EndDate date, -- and here!
    subscription_Cost number(6) CONSTRAINT Subscription_Cost_Check 
        CHECK (Subscription_Cost > 0),
    CONSTRAINT Subscription_pk PRIMARY KEY (Club_ID, Member_ID),
    CONSTRAINT club_fk FOREIGN KEY (Club_ID) REFERENCES Club(Club_ID) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT Member_fk FOREIGN KEY (Member_ID) REFERENCES Member(Member_ID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```